# What's this line between the modeline and the echo area?

Tags: window, themes, mode-line, echo-area, gui-emacs

[image: shot-1]

I'm using a dark theme, so it's a bit hard to see, but there is a black line between the modeline and the echo area in the shot above. You can also see it between the modeline and a hydra, and the hydra and the echo area below.

[image: shot-2]

Any idea what this is, so I can get rid of it if possible?

Comment: Could you please tell me about the font in the screenshots ?

Comment: @displayname Sure, it's a free Mozilla font called [Fira Mono](https://mozilla.github.io/Fira/). If you're using an editor that supports OpenType features (not Emacs, unfortunately), there's a modified version called [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) that includes programming ligatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using my [Emacs theme](https://github.com/hlissner/emacs-doom-theme) and could be using my [emacs.d config](https://github.com/hlissner/.emacs.d), I suspect you have `window-divider-mode` enabled, which adds this border. You can either:

- Set the bottom border's width to 0: `(setq window-divider-default-bottom-width 0)`
- Turn off the bottom border: `(setq window-divider-default-places 'right-only)`
- or turn off `window-divider-mode` altogether: `(window-divider-mode -1)`

For reference, here is my `window-divider-mode` config, taken from [core/core-ui.el](https://github.com/hlissner/.emacs.d/blob/master/core/core-ui.el#L103) :

```
;; `window-divider-mode' gives us finer control over the border between windows.
;; The native border "consumes" a pixel of the left fringe on righter-most splits
;; (in Yamamoto's emacs-mac at least), window-divider does not.
;; NOTE Only available on Emacs 25.1+
(when (boundp 'window-divider-mode)
  (setq window-divider-default-places t
        window-divider-default-bottom-width 1
        window-divider-default-right-width 1)
  (window-divider-mode +1))
```